# Python excuting Ubuntu commands

Tags: python

I made this:

```
import os

os.system("cd /home/k/Documents/Avr")

a = raw_input("1-for ATmega32A 2-ATmega328P")

if (a == 1) :
    os.system("cd ATmega32")
if (a == 2):
    os.system("cd ATmega328P")
```

but it just ends and i'm back on desktop where this python file was!!!

I want to make python app that takes my MCU modle (1 or 2) and then the .c file/folder name and then automatically compile and flash it to my mcu!!! ("using avr-gcc and avrdude")

Comment: You cannot change the cwd of a parent-process in a child-process:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python but this might be okay, if you do your work in the same child-process too. Consider this example: python -c 'import os; os.chdir("/home/madmike/Downloads"); os.system("pwd")'

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
os.chdir(mypath)
```